# Drupal core search no longer finds any results

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

All of the sudden my drupal core search is no longer finding nodes no matter what i search for. I have tried using core themes, i have no other search modules, i see the search tables in the db. I have tried reindexing and running cron. Any ideas? I have tons of other sites with this same config but search is running fine.

Comment: Have you installed any new modules or modified any config files recently? Have you looked at the watchdog logs to see if any errors are logged there? Do you have access to the Apache error logs to see if anything is there? Any little bit of information will be helpful.

Comment: Turns out there was malicious code inside search.module. Thanks for taking the time to respond!